# Efeito Celular CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Gostaria muito de aprender este efeito nas vantagens do aplicativo no site
https://www.linx.com.br/payhub/shopbit/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI65qB46-n3wIVEoORCh1Xxg9iEAAYASAAEgJlS_D_BwE

Efeito visto no link
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Alguém sabe como fazer esse efeito visto acima?**

Eu tentei desta forma usando `parallax` e `border-image` juntamente com o `tabs` do Bootstrap 4

```
 body {
  position: relative;
}
ul.nav-pills {
  top: 20px;
  position: fixed;
}
div.col-8 div {
  height: 500px;
}
.borda {
 border: 10px solid transparent;
 padding: 15px;
 border-image-source: url(phone.png);
 border-image-repeat: round;
 border-image-slice: 30;
 border-image-width: 20px;
}
.parallax {
/* The image used */
background-image: url('https://img.elo7.com.br/product/zoom/FBCE34/adesivo- paisagem-praia-decorando-com-adesivos.jpg');
height: 100%; 
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
 }



<div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <nav class="col-sm-3 col-4" id="myScrollspy">
              <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link active" href="#section1">Section 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#section2">Section 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#section3">Section 3</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-3 borda">
              <div class="parallax"></div>
              <div id="section1" class="bg-success">    
                <h1>Section 1</h1>
                <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
              </div>
              <div class="parallax"></div>
              <div id="section2" class="bg-warning"> 
                <h1>Section 2</h1>
                <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
              </div>  
              <div class="parallax"></div>      
              <div id="section3" class="bg-secondary">         
                <h1>Section 3</h1>
                <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Seria interessande vc colocar na sua pergunta alguns detalhes a mais, ou se vc já tiver algum código ajudaria. Esse é um modelo bem tranquilo de se fazer, e existem vários formas diferentes de faze-lo inclusive apenas com CSS que é o que te sugiro...

Comment: ah sim, então eu não tenho nenhum código ainda, tentei algumas coisas que pesquisei, mas sem sucesso por isso perguntei aqui. gostaria de saber como fazer ou por onde começar rs

Comment: Qualquer coisa que vc já tenha tentado já pode dar uma ideia do problema que vc está tendo. Esse é o ponto do site, estamos aqui para te ajudar a entender e resolver um problema. Não para entregar um código pronto, que no final das contas não te ajudaria em nada a crescer entende. Tente falar onde está sua dificuldade, ou exatamente até onde chegou e agarrou pq não sabe mais como proceder. Não precisa ser um exemplo bonito = o do link, mas algo mais básico só pra vc testar a dinâmica e por pra funcionar entende.

Comment: Você pode sempre abrir as ferramentas de desenvolvedor e inspecionar os elementos em questão; assim você verá quais elementos e quais propriedades foram utilizadas e buscar aprendê-los.

Comment: ah claro,adicionei o codigo que tentei fazer. obrigada pessoal

Answer (score -1):

```css
*{
 text-align: center;
}

#geral{
 margin: 10px auto;
 background-color: #ddd;
 width: 300px;
 height: 350px;
 color: white;
 overflow:hidden;
}

#geral div{
 width: 300px;
 height: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
 animation: aniOut 0.3s 1;
} 

#geral input[type="radio"]{display: none}

#geral input[type="radio"]:checked + div{
 display: block;
 height: 350px;
 animation: aniIn 0.3s 1;
 overflow:hidden;
}

@keyframes aniIn{
 0%{height: 0px}
 100%{height: 350px}
}

@keyframes aniOut{
 0%{height: 350px}
 100%{height: 0px}
}

#geral div:nth-child(4n+2){background-color: #2c3e50}
#geral div:nth-child(4n+4){background-color: #222}
```

```html
<button><label for="c1">CONTEUDO 1</label></button>
<button><label for="c2">CONTEUDO 2</label></button>
<button><label for="c3">CONTEUDO 3</label></button>
<button><label for="c4">CONTEUDO 4</label></button>
<button><label for="c5">CONTEUDO 5</label></button>



<div id="geral">

 <input type="radio" id="c1" name="group">
 <div>
  <h1>teste 1</h1>
  <p>conteudo 1</p>
 </div>

 <input type="radio" id="c2" name="group">
 <div>
  <h1>teste 2</h1>
  <p>conteudo 2</p>
 </div>

 <input type="radio" id="c3" name="group">
 <div>
  <h1>teste 3</h1>
  <p>conteudo 3</p>
 </div>

 <input type="radio" id="c4" name="group">
 <div>
  <h1>teste 4</h1>
  <p>conteudo 4</p>
 </div>

  <input type="radio" id="c5" name="group">
 <div>
  <h1>teste 5</h1>
  <p>conteudo 5</p>
 </div>
</div>
```